# My css dropdown menu's won't show the sub menu

Tags: html, css, menu, web

The sub menu doesn't show up when i hover over the tabs and I have been trying to find a fix for a few days. I have been going over the syntax for a while and I feel like I need a new pair of eyes. Please help as soon as possible.

```
<header id="header" class="HeaderStyle" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
<p style="font-size: xx-large; width: 400px;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-right: 0%;"> Sherwood Lego League</p>
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" style="text-align:right; width: 99%;">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="25" maxlength="255" value="" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="www.SherwoodLegoLeague.com">
</form>
<navigation id="NavigationLink" class="navigationStyle">
    <section class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="left_nosub" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="center_hassub" href="teams/teams.html">Teams</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="teams/team1.html">Team 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="teams/team2.html">Team 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="teams/team3.html">Team 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="teams/team4.html">Team 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="teams/team5.html">Team 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="center_hassub" href="news/news.html">News</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="news/article.html">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="news/timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="right_nosub" href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</navigation>
</header>
```

CSS section

```
.menu {
   font-family: "TimesNewRoman", Times, serif;
   position: relative;
   font-size: 11px;
   margin: 0;
   z-index: 1000;
}
.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 81px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/center.png');
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
.menu .left_nosub {
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/left.png');
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
.menu .right_nosub {
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/right.png');
}
.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #000;
    background: url('../images/MenuPieces/center_hassub.png');
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li a.center_hassub {
    background: #6a3;
    color: #000;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover a.center_hassub {
    background: #6fc;
    color: #000;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover .left_nosub {
    color: #000;
    background: url('../images/MenuPieces/left_nosub.png');
}
.menu ul li:hover .right_hassub {
    color: #000;
    background: url('../images/MenuPieces/right_hassub.png');
}
.menu ul li:hover .right_nosub {
    color: #000;
    background: url('../images/MenuPieces/right_nosub.png');
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    background-image: none;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #000;
    width: 142px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/dropdown.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
}
.menu  ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/sub_hover.png');
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    top: 0;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.left {
    left: -105px;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul .sub_active {
    background-image: url('../images/MenuPieces/sub_active.png');
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hid them by default but you forgot to add a display property to them upon hover. You need to add something like `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` or similar property to the `.menu  ul li:hover ul li a:hover` and `.menu ul li:hover ul` selectors.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/z27hu0cb/)

Comment: that gets me still aren't totally fixed closer but the

Comment: @BrandonRath Sorry, did your sentence get scrambled accidentally? I can't understand you.

Comment: ya sorry "that gets me closer but still aren't totally fixed." I can see them but the textures aren't there and they aren't lined up either.

Comment: @BrandonRath Ah. Well, the images are stored locally, so if they aren't appearing, it is likely that the relative filepaths are incorrect. Try with the URL of a placeholder image hosted online somewhere to test that theory.

Comment: A lot of your css under "ul li a" should be under "ul li". Like background, width, padding and height. That might solve some of your problems.

Comment: @ShaneLessard If you're referring to Brandon, it might be helpful to tag him in the comment so he sees it :-) My Fiddle just uses his code from above (minus adding the display properties, of course).

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li:hover ul { 
display:block;
}
```

Have something like this, so that when you hover over ul li, you display ul.